# Limitations of FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the limitations for fcm? like,

1. how many notification can send for a day,
2. Is there any billing option for fcm usage

Tell me I'm new to fcm

Answer (score 1):

> how many notification can send for a day,

There is no simple limit for number of messages per day.  You should read and understand the limits in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) for specific details on limits in various circumstances.

> Is there any billing option for fcm usage

No, there is no billing for FCM.  Refer to the [pricing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).